# How to implement an ordered singly linked list in Rust?

Tags: rust, linked-list

I have a fully functioning singly linked list.  The only thing I want to do extra is add a value to order by so that when you push() an item, it crawls the list and inserts the node in the right spot so that when the list is popped, the lowest ranked node is always popped first.

Here is the link in the playground.  How do I do this?

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fad1e1e650fa7265e392b2adec7d5d13)

The snippet here, the add() method is :

```
// Push will insert according to rank - rank is ordered lowest first
pub fn push(&mut self, elem: T, rank: i32) {
    for ranked_node in self.head.iter_mut() {
        if let Some(next) = ranked_node.next.as_mut() {
            if next.rank >= rank {
                // If the next is larger, add here
                let new_node = Box::new(Node {
                    rank: rank,
                    elem: elem, 
                    // New node points to next
                    next: Some(*next),
                });
                // set current node to our new noded
                ranked_node.next = Some(new_node);
                break;   
            }
            // Else iterate to next
        } else {
            // There is no higher next node, add at end
            let new_node = Box::new(Node {
                rank: rank,
                elem: elem, 
                next: None,
            });
            ranked_node.next = Some(new_node);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The error in its current form is

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*next` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src/lib.rs:29:36
   |
29 |                         next: Some(*next),
   |                                    ^^^^^ move occurs because `*next` has type `Box<Node<T>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
error: could not compile `playground` (lib) due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: could not compile `playground` (lib test) due to previous error
```

I tried using mem::take() but that requires Defaults to be implemented and that does not seem right. Link is a reference, why can't I just copy it?  Do I have to implement copy?

Actually, I've made some progress on fixing this.  In essence, the direct answer to my question is use Option::take().  You are swapping something for None.

```
pub struct List<T> {
    head: Link<T>,
}

type Link<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

struct Node<T> {
    rank: i32,
    elem: T,
    next: Link<T>,
}

impl<T> List<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        List { head: None }
    }

    // Push will insert according to rank - rank is ordered lowest first
    pub fn push(&mut self, elem: T, rank: i32) {
        if Option::is_none(&self.head) {
            let new_node = Box::new(Node {
                rank,
                elem, 
                next: None,
            });
            self.head = Some(new_node);
        } else {
            for ranked_node in self.head.iter_mut() {
                if let Some(ref next) = ranked_node.next {
                    if next.rank >= rank {
                        // If the next is larger, add here
                        let new_node = Box::new(Node {
                            rank,
                            elem, 
                            // New node points to next
                            next: Option::take(&mut ranked_node.next),
                        });
                        // set current node to our new noded
                        ranked_node.next = Some(new_node);
                        break;   
                    }
                    // Else iterate to next
                } else {
                    // There is no higher next node, add at end
                    let new_node = Box::new(Node {
                        rank,
                        elem, 
                        next: None,
                    });
                    ranked_node.next = Some(new_node);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        self.head.take().map(|node| {
            self.head = node.next;
            node.elem
        })
    }

    pub fn peek(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        self.head.as_ref().map(|node| {
            &node.elem
        })
    }

    pub fn peek_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut T> {
        self.head.as_mut().map(|node| {
            &mut node.elem
        })
    }

    pub fn into_iter(self) -> IntoIter<T> {
        IntoIter(self)
    }

    pub fn iter(&self) -> Iter<'_, T> {
        Iter { next: self.head.as_deref() }
    }

    pub fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> IterMut<'_, T> {
        IterMut { next: self.head.as_deref_mut() }
    }
}

impl<T> Drop for List<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let mut cur_link = self.head.take();
        while let Some(mut boxed_node) = cur_link {
            cur_link = boxed_node.next.take();
        }
    }
}

pub struct IntoIter<T>(List<T>);

impl<T> Iterator for IntoIter<T> {
    type Item = T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        // access fields of a tuple struct numerically
        self.0.pop()
    }
}

pub struct Iter<'a, T> {
    next: Option<&'a Node<T>>,
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.next.map(|node| {
            self.next = node.next.as_deref();
            &node.elem
        })
    }
}

pub struct IterMut<'a, T> {
    next: Option<&'a mut Node<T>>,
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for IterMut<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a mut T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.next.take().map(|node| {
            self.next = node.next.as_deref_mut();
            &mut node.elem
        })
    }
}
```

Here is the semi-working code in rust playground  [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4231005c536529feb9758468f8034a96)

BUT, there is either a higher level logic problem here or a rust bug.  The code only works for 2 elements.  When I add the 3rd element, the for loop exits before getting to the last item so the 3rd element is never added.  Have I corrupted memory with substitutions?

I think in the line above

```
 if let Some(ref next) = ranked_node.next {
```

breaks the iterator?  I just want to look ahead one link while iterating!

So I tried adding an accesor method to Node that will look ahead and do a copy of i32 out of the next Node.

```
impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn next_rank(&self) -> Option<i32> {
        self.next.as_ref().map(|node| {
            node.rank
        })        
    }
}
```

And use it like this ...

```
if let Some(next_rank) = ranked_node.next_rank() {
```

But the iterator behaves the same.  It does not iterate to the 3rd element.

And here is another variant, it is ugly, but it is more explicit and shows the same problem .. this looks like a bug to me in Rust.

A look-ahead function that returns the rank value as i32 :

```
impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn next_rank(&self) -> i32 {
        match self.next.as_ref() {
            Some(n) => {n.rank},
            _ => -1
        }
    }
}
```

The iterator is now just using next() :

```
// Push will insert according to rank - rank is ordered lowest first
pub fn push(&mut self, elem: T, rank: i32) {
    if Option::is_none(&self.head) {
        let new_node = Box::new(Node {
            rank,
            elem, 
            next: None,
        });
        self.head = Some(new_node);
    } else {
        let mut miter = self.head.iter_mut();
        loop {
            let ranked_node = miter.next(); 
            if ranked_node.is_some() {
                let curr_node = ranked_node.unwrap();
                let next_rank = curr_node.next_rank();
                if next_rank >= 0  {
                    // If the current value to insert is less than 
                    //   the next node's value, insert here
                    if next_rank >= rank {
                        // If the next is larger, add here
                        let new_node = Box::new(Node {
                            rank,
                            elem, 
                            // New node points to next
                            next: Option::take(&mut curr_node.next),
                        });
                        // set current node to our new noded
                        curr_node.next = Some(new_node);
                        break;   
                    }
                } else {
                    // There is no higher next node, add at end
                    let new_node = Box::new(Node {
                        rank,
                        elem, 
                        next: None,
                    });
                    curr_node.next = Some(new_node);
                    break;                        
                }
            } else {
                // There is no higher next node, add at end
                let new_node = Box::new(Node {
                    rank,
                    elem, 
                    next: None,
                });
                // This fails - ranked_node is None but it should be the 2nd element
                ranked_node.unwrap().next = Some(new_node);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can call `Option::take` instead of `as_mut`, and then put it back after (if it isn't inserted). There are many unexpected things to implementing linked lists in rust, which is why there's this helpful article: [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)

Comment: Rust only allows you to do things with a generic ( <T> ) that you specify; if you want it to be able to Copy, you have to say so; <T: Copy>. However, Copy is not what you want here. mem::take is a good way to do this, you have to not be initializing a default value though, if you aren't requiring the Default trait.

Comment: There is no Rust bug but `self.head.iter_mut()` probably doesn't invoke the method you think it does, it calls [`Option::iter_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.iter_mut), not your method, which you should show here by the way a [mre] has to be included **within** the post, not *just* on external resources and only linked.

Answer (score 0):

The key points were use of `Option::take`, and losing track of iterator over a list and over an option.  But also, over use of the same variable name 'next' caused confusion. And finally, added a helper method on the Node.

The final push method looks like this, it may not be beautiful but it works:

```
impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn look_forward_node_rank(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
        self.next.as_ref().map(|node| {
            node.rank
        })
    }
}
//...
    pub fn push(&mut self, elem: T, rank: i32) {
        if self.head.is_none() {
            // A new list, push first node
            let new_node = Box::new(Node {
                rank,
                elem,
                next: self.head.take(),
            });

            self.head = Some(new_node);
        } else {
            let mut find_node = self.iter_mut();
            loop {
                let curr_node = find_node.ptr.as_deref_mut();
                match curr_node {
                    Some(node) => {     
                        match node.look_forward_node_rank() {
                            Some(next_rank) =>  {            
                                if next_rank > rank {
                                    let new_node = Box::new(Node {
                                        rank,
                                        elem,
                                        next:  Option::take(&mut node.next),
                                    });
                                    node.next = Some(new_node);
                                    break;  
                                }    
                            },
                            _ => {
                                // At the end of the list
                                let new_node = Box::new(Node {
                                    rank,
                                    elem,
                                    next: None,
                                });
                    
                                node.next = Some(new_node);
                                break;                    
                            }                            
                        }
                    },
                    _ => { panic!("iter_mut()") } // Should not get here
                }
                find_node.next(); // want side effect of incrementing ptr                
            }
        }
    }
```

Final answer in playground:  [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5ac24762c10be5e6613a06fc9b93c74e)